# UITableView: How to 'fix' current cell after row insertion?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView. I want to insert some rows at the top of table. But after the insertion, the old cells are pushed down.

```
NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

For example:
Before insertion:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
- ...

After insertion

- Item -5
- Item -4
- Item -3
- ...
- Item 1
- Item 2
- ...

I want keep Item 1 to its 'old position', for example:

After insertion

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- ...

And the new inserted cells are above the old(not shown on the screen).

Comment: Set scroll position in UITableView ... [theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedScrollPosition inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by myself. I think it is more smooth and has better user experience.

```
    for (Poi *poi in fetchedObjects) {
        [self.objects insertObject: poi atIndex: 0];
    }

    CGFloat totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<fetchedObjects.count; ++i) {
        totalHeight += [self tableView: self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0]];
    }

    CGPoint currentContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    currentContentOffset.y += totalHeight;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.tableView.contentOffset = currentContentOffset;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:value atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Note the value will be the indexPath with the row count as the number of new rows that you have added.

To create indexPath use,

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]
```

Comment: It can solve the problem, but not the best solution. The screen flickers a few times, it is not good user experience.

Comment: Add all the rows and then scroll to the first row ? So that will ensure the screen flickers only once. So i guess that should not be a problem.